# MySQL Query with Date_Sub returns empty set on query, but count = 1 when join is included

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a dataset of the last active chat users on my site, however the where clause in the query is "failing" and returning results that have "expired"...

The following is what I would expect...

```
mysql> select * from openchats where date_sub(now(), interval 15 minute) < active;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

However, I am joining a couple of tables to make my life easier, and the join query returns a count of 1 when I expect zero...

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->   (
    ->     COUNT(*)
    ->   ) AS `count`
    -> FROM
    ->   openchats Openchats
    ->   LEFT JOIN users Users ON Users.id = (Openchats.user_id)
    ->   LEFT JOIN chatrooms Chatrooms ON Chatrooms.id = (Openchats.chatroom_id)
    -> WHERE
    ->   (
    ->     DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 15 minute) < 'Openchats.active'
    ->     AND open = 1
    ->   );
+-------+
| count |
+-------+
|     1 |
+-------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Here is the data for the table

```
mysql> select * from openchats;
+----+-------------+------+---------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | chatroom_id | open | active              | user_id                              | created             | modified            |
+----+-------------+------+---------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |           3 |    1 | 2017-07-31 19:14:33 | 3f189dab-597a-468f-8f6f-ae577a8e05e8 | 2017-07-31 18:38:00 | 2017-07-31 18:38:00 |
+----+-------------+------+---------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Can anyone explain to me how I can make the second query return a count of zero?

Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your mistake is in the following line:

```
DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 15 minute) < 'Openchats.active'
```

You are comparing the result of DATE_SUB to the string 'Openchats.active', rather than the active attribute of the Openchats table. Try removing the quotes and running it again:

```
DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 15 minute) < Openchats.active
```